# Birational model of a log smooth pair

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, toric-varieties, resolution-of-singularities

Given a log smooth pair $(X,B)$ with a reduced boundary divisor $B$, consider a birational model $\pi:X' \to X$ and a boundary divisor $B'$ which is given by $K_{X'}+B'=\pi^*(K_X+B)$. Here is my question:

(1) can we construct an example that $(X',B')$ is not sub-dlt?

(2) is there an lc center of $(X',B')$ which is not an irreducible component of an intersection locus of some certain components of $B'^{=1}$ (this means the coefficient one part of $B'$)?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{A}^2$ with the two lines, and then you blow-up $(x,y^n)$? So I think the answer to the first one is yes. The second answer should be no, the morphism $X'\rightarrow X$ should be toroidal around the divisors with coefficient one.

Comment: The second answer should be no, the morphism $X′\to X$ should be toroidal around the divisors with coefficient one. Thank you! This is exactly what I need. Could you please offer a reference or something? The term "toroidal" is really confusing to me..